# undefined control sequence problem \listoffigures and \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, undefined

I am using the LaTeX template given in this link:
http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=rquf20#Formatting_and_templates

This journal requires a list of figure captions which I am trying to do using `\listoffigures`. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{rQUF2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, 


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
some figures

\bibliographystyle{rQUF}
\bibliography{BibTeX1}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

However, when compiling this code in “TeXnicCenter”, it keeps saying `\listoffigures` is an undefined control sequence. The same thing happens if I use `\listoftables`. Does anyone know why this is happening? Any possible workarounds? I’d like to avoid manually writing out all the figure captions by hand again in a separate document.

Comment: The answer is pretty easy. This class does not provide `\listoffigures` etc. macros. As it stands, you don't have any figure in your MWE however, so `\listoffigure` would be pretty useless. It also ships the totally deprecated `subfigure` package which causes trouble

Comment: You could ask the journal exactly what they mean with "(as a list)", but given that the template doesn't provide `\listoffigures`, it seems unlikely that that is what they mean. (Could be that at final submission you simply move all the `figure` environments to the end of the `.tex` file.)

Comment: I see. Well the journal says we should provide a list of figure captions at the end of the document, so the figures will be inside the main body of text. The captions will be at the end, which is why I tried to use \listoffigures. I find it strange how they require this, yet do not provide support for this command. 

Is there any way I can define something similar that would also do the same job? There are a lot of figures so I would not like to manually copy all the figure captions as them I would have to make they sure they matched all the figure numbers.

Comment: Does anyone know if I can maybe manually define something similar to \listoffigures?

Comment: Did you actually ask the journal what they mean? I haven't published in that journal (or even with that publisher, for that matter), so I can't be sure, but what I would do is to move all the `figure` environments to the end of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the website of the journal does indeed state that figure captions should be at the end of the document, and figures should be included within the appropriate location within the main text. I guess the best solution is to create a list of figure captions as an appendix. Very strange indeed that they wouldn't add support for it in the template they have provided.